# Can't run my jquery code in blade file on Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to run a jquery code that shows an enlarged model when clicked. I tested it using a raw html/css/js program and it works well. However, when trying to put it onto my laravel program, it looks like my blade file isn't picking up on the jquery code. I placed the js code in my public/js/external.js file. Here's my script code that I placed at the end of my blade code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="public/js/external.js"></script>
```

Can anyone tell me what's the problem? I will be happy to provide more information.

Edit: Here is my index.blade.php

```
<div class="py-12">

  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              @if(session('success'))
                  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                      <strong>{{ session('success') }}</strong>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    @endif                    
              <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">All models</div>
          <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">SL No</th>
                  <th scope="col">Model Name</th>
                  <th scope="col">Model Image</th>
                  <th scope="col">Description</th>
                  <th scope="col">Version</th>
                  <th scope="col">Created At</th>
                  <th scope="col">Modify</th></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  {{-- @php($i =1)   --}}
                  @if(count($items)>0)
                  @foreach($items as $item)
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">{{ $items->firstItem()+$loop->index}}</th>
                  <td>{{ $item->model_name }}</td>
                  <td><model-viewer class="small-image" src="{{ asset($item->model_image) }}"alt=""auto-rotate="" camera-controls="" background-color="#455A64"></model-viewer></td> {{-- The part where users can click and and an enlarged model will appear --}}
                  
                  <td>{{ $item->description }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $item->version }}</td>
                  <td>
                      @if($item->created_at == NULL)
                      <span class="text-danger"> No Date Set </span>
                      @else
                      {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->diffForHumans() }} {{-- Carbon needed for query builder --}}
                      @endif
                  </td> 
                  <td>
                      <a href="{{ url('model/download/'.$item->id) }}"class="btn btn-success">Download</a>
                      <a href="{{ url('model/view/'.$item->model_name) }}"class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
                      <a href="{{ url('model/edit/'.$item->id) }}"class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
                @else
                <td>No records found</td>
                @endif
              </tbody>
            </table>
            {{ $items->links() }}
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

|

```
<div id="show_image_popup">
<div class="close-btn-area">
  
</div>
<div id="image-show-area">
    <model-viewer class="clickModel"  id="large-image" alt=""auto-rotate="" camera-controls="" background-color="#455A64"></model-viewer>
</div>
```

And here is my external.js:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){



  $("#close-btn").click(function(){
     // remove active class from all images
    $(".small-image").removeClass('active');
    $("#show_image_popup").slideUp();
  })

  $(".small-image").click(function(){
      // remove active class from all images
     alert('HUH');
     $(".small-image").removeClass('active');
    // add active class
     $(this).addClass('active');

    var image_path = $(this).attr('src'); 
    
    
    
    $("#large-image").attr('src',image_path);

  })
```

})

The alert function works when I click on any model, but a pop-up modal should appear when I click on it. [What happens when I click on a model image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjAWI.png).

Comment: Call your `external.js` like `<script src="{{ asset('js/external.js') }}"></script>` and sure that your`external.js` it should be in `/public/js/external.js` directory @x-l-m-25

Comment: @Siddharth Hi, I tried placing the script at the start of my blade file between <head>.

Answer (score 0):

See how your blade has `@yield('content')` You will want to add one in the footer for scripts such as `@yield('scripts')` - Thats in your base blade.

example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
        <script src="your main app script here.">
        @yield('scripts')
    </body>
</html>
```

Then in your view you can do

```
@section('content')
 your page content.
@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script>
 // your jQuery here.
</script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

**Go to the view source page and check the scripts are there and linked properly.**

**Master layout blade-like app.blade.php:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
    </div>

    @stack('script')
</body>
```

**Child blade:**

```
@section('content')
 your page content.
@endsection

@push('script')
 your both scripts
@endpush
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your jquery link is the first js you included, ordering is so important while including your assets.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to what @siddharth mentioned can you please check by adding alert in document.ready to check if your Jquery is loaded or not.

Also you can check JS related errors in console to have better idea it would be good if you can check and attach screenshot of console if there are any errors.

Comment: Hi, I have added the alert function when clicking the model image(You can see my edit) and it works. However a pop-up modal is supposed to be appearing.

Comment: Hi @x_l_m_25 ,

it means Jquery is working well..

I noticed that you havent written jquery to call/open modal ..can you check by adding below and add a call to open modal on any particular action like on button click as mentioned below

If you're using modal of jquery then you can do like below : 

`$('#button1').on('click', function() {
    $('#show_image_popup').show();
});`

or if you're using Bootstrap Modal then you can use 

`$('#show_image_popup').modal('toggle'); OR $('#show_image_popup').modal('show'); `

Comment: I will try to add a button for that. However, isn't the class in<model-viewer **class="small-image"** src="{{ asset($item->model_image) }}"alt=""auto-rotate="" camera-controls="" background-color="#455A64"></model-viewer></td> considered a button that opens up the modal since it links to the jquery code?

Comment: True that can be used as well but still you need to add a trigger of opening a modal in your code.. like mentioned in my last comment to open your modal

Comment: Hi  @x_l_m_25 ,

If what i shared helped you to resolve issue you can mark my answer accepted answer.

Thanks !